# Change Database Connection Settings or Manager From Symfony Repository

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I'm working on this proof of concept where a Symfony App can have a Master-Slave MongoDB setup where the Master is a remote MongoDB replica set while the slave is a single instance run locally. The local instance *cannot* be part of the replica set but is kept in sync by a third party extension i.e not by MongoDB itself.

I currently have all this setup and working just fine using multiple Document managers called default and readonly. Thankfully, I was able to reuse the mappings without need for change.

I now want to have a few people try this out but having them to change their code would be a big hindrance. So I was thinking of the best way. Since it's only reads that will be directed to a local Mongo instance I was thinking maybe extending the custom repos would work, perhaps a listener to change the connection settings when I detect a read query. Can't find any resource to let me do so if possible.

Can anyone think of the best way?

Comment: in your Controller you can get info from request, whether it's an READ action, if so you can use a different entity/document manager - what is your exact question here?

Comment: Maybe this can be a good inspiration http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connections.MasterSlaveConnection.html

Comment: @LBA thanks but its not about the request-response cycle. It's about switching (or confirming) the db connection to a specific host on read. Symfony allows this via multiple document managers but I was asking for another way.

Comment: @Mawcel exactly, that link really is what I am looking to do but hopefully from the document manager/repository layer rather than DBAL. The link helps a lot with getting me started... or inspired, thanks!